# Use of the word ‘different’

Tags: word-usage

Here are some examples of 'different' from the Internet:

1. […] visited several schools in three different communities […]
2. […] the verses of Kabir have four different senses; illusion, spirit, intellect, and the exoteric doctrine of the Vedas.
3. In November 1805, Prince Vasili had to go on a tour of inspection in four different provinces.
4. Google Research Intern, PhD, 2021 in 8 different countries.
5. On two (n) different occasions.
   And a question asked on EL&U, which came up as I was posting:
6. How many different parts of speech can the f-word be used as?

What is the added value of using 'different' in these sentences?

The only meaningful meanings I can ascribe are either ‘unusual’ or ‘various’. If any of the other definitions apply, the constructions become, in my perception, redundant.

Take for instance #2. The four senses are obviously different, so why stress it? By a stretch of imagination, I can assume it means unusual/special.

But what about #4.? Is Google looking for RIs to work in ‘unusual/special’ countries and not in the common or ordinary ones?

In the case of #3., the word ‘different’ does not appear in the source Russian text. So, ‘in four provinces’ should suffice.

Finally, to keep it short(er), is #6. about ‘unusual’ parts of speech? I think not.

It seems to me that, in many such cases, ‘different’ is used simply because it is available.

These are the definitions of ‘different’ in the online MW Dictionary (partially quoted):

1: partly or totally unlike in nature, form, or quality : DISSIMILAR
2: not the same: such as
a: DISTINCT
different age groups
b: VARIOUS
different members of the class
c: ANOTHER
switched to a different TV program
3: UNUSUAL, SPECIAL
she was different and superior

Comment: In #2 and #6, it means _distinct from one another_. In the others, I would say it means _various_. It may be (technically) redundant, but it is very commonly used in this kind of context. Maybe '8 different countries' emphasises that they are countries in various parts of the world and not all neighbouring ones?

Comment: All six examples mean *different as* ***distinct***. But to my ear, they all beg the sarcastic "No, the 8 different countries were the same country!"

Answer (score 1):

> 1. […] visited several schools in three different communities […]
> 2. […] the verses of Kabir have four different senses; illusion, spirit, intellect, and the exoteric doctrine of the Vedas.
> 3. In November 1805, Prince Vasili had to go on a tour of inspection in four different provinces.
> 4. Google Research Intern, PhD, 2021 in 8 different countries.
> 5. On two (n) different occasions.
> 6. How many different parts of speech can the f-word be used as?

(a) In most of these examples, omitting 'different' would have the pragmatic effect of making the sentence sound weaker. 'They visited schools in three communities' for instance sounds less emphatic, somehow less committed, than when 'different' is included. Redundancy has to be balanced against this.

(b) As Greybeard says, 'different' also carries the meaning of

> - not alike in character or quality; distinct in nature; dissimilar:
>
> *The two brothers are very different even though they're identical twins.*

[[Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/different)]

and at least example (1) carries this sense as a denotation/connotation.

(c) 'Different' also carries the 'distinct' [non-overlapping] sense:

> - distinct; separate.
>   *on two different occasions*

[[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/different)]

I'd say this sense is at least strongly connoted in example (2), and hinted at in most of the others.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the added value of using 'different' in these sentences?

"**Different**" is added in a sense of "having individual differences" when the speaker or writer then intends to enumerate those differences.